# Why can I not declare a top-level GTKMM objects?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, global-variables, gtk, gtkmm

I am old to GTK+ (C) but new to GTKMM and adapted a very simple example app from some [example code](https://www.gtk.org/docs/language-bindings/cpp).

```
#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <iostream>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");
    Gtk::Window win;
    Gtk::Button m_button("Hello World");
    m_button.signal_clicked().connect([](){
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    });
    win.set_border_width(10);
    win.add(m_button);
    m_button.show();
    return app->run(win);
}
```

This works as expected, creating a window with a <kbd>Hello World</kbd> button that prints `Hello World` when clicked.

> ```
> Hello World
> Hello World
> Hello World
> ```

I am not entirely sure how this memory is allocated in C++, but I thought using static memory as opposed to heap memory would be better, and this could potentially be achieved by moving some of the declarations to the top level. Or if I just want to access these later on from separate functions:

```
#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <iostream>
Gtk::Window win;
Gtk::Button m_button("Hello World");
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");
    m_button.signal_clicked().connect([](){
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    });
    win.set_border_width(10);
    win.add(m_button);
    m_button.show();
    return app->run(win);
}
```

That does **not** work as expected.

> ```
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ```

Why does GTKMM and/or C++ not like the *'global'*/top-level variables? Can someone explain what is going on behind the scenes, or how I could have a top-level object without this error?

Comment: FWIW `win` and `m_button` weren't on the heap to begin with. (Well, probably--technically "heap" and "stack" are implementation details, and the C++ standard only cares about automatic vs dynamic storage duration.)

Comment: Perhaps `Gtk::Application::create` does some stuff that the other declarations require in order to work correctly. What happens if you move the globals inside main but before the `create` call?

Comment: @RetiredNinja `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Application.html#details) `Note
Most widgets can't safely be created before the application has been registered (Gio::Application::register_application() called) or activated (Gio::Application::signal_activate() emitted). They can't safely be deleted after run() or make_window_and_run() returns.` My quick read of that and the behavior you are seeing sounds like you must call `create` to initialize things before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the segfault is indeed what was mentioned by @Retired Ninja in the comments. You should not try to instantiate widgets before the toolkit has been initialized, through a call to `Gtk::Application::create`. That being said, you could use "top level" variables.

#### Solution 1 (heap)

You can use `std::unique_ptr` (specifically designed to own a single resource, such as a widget) to store your "top level" variables.

For example:

```cpp
#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <iostream>
std::unique_ptr<Gtk::Window> win;
std::unique_ptr<Gtk::Button> m_button;
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");

    win = std::make_unique<Gtk::Window>();
    m_button = std::make_unique<Gtk::Button>("Hello World");

    m_button->signal_clicked().connect([](){
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    });
    win->set_border_width(10);
    win->add(*m_button);
    m_button->show();
    return app->run(*win);
}
```

These lines:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Gtk::Window> win;
std::unique_ptr<Gtk::Button> m_button;
```

instantiate unique pointers to a window and a button, but do not instantiate the widgets themselves (the pointer value is `nullptr` here), which is fine because at this time, the application has not been created. These lines:

```cpp
win = std::make_unique<Gtk::Window>();
m_button = std::make_unique<Gtk::Button>("Hello World");
```

instantiate the widgets (on the heap) and assign them to our unique pointers. This *must* happen *after* the application has been created otherwise you will get a segfault as before.

With this solution, notice how all syntax has turned to pointer syntax (using `*` to access the widgets and `->` to call methods on it).

#### Solution 2 (stack)

You could use free functions that return `static` instances of your widgets. Wrapping the creation of the `static` variables in functions allows you to control the time of creation of these variables (on the stack). The use of `static` will make sure the widgets live for the whole lifespan of the program (if this is what you want).

For example:

```cpp
#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <iostream>

Gtk::Window& TopLevelWindowGet()
{
    static Gtk::Window window;
    return window;
}

Gtk::Button& TopLevelButtonGet()
{
    static Gtk::Button button("Hello World");
    return button;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");

    Gtk::Window& win = TopLevelWindowGet();
    Gtk::Button& m_button = TopLevelButtonGet();

    m_button.signal_clicked().connect([](){
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    });
    win.set_border_width(10);
    win.add(m_button);
    m_button.show();
    return app->run(win);
}
```

These lines:

```cpp
Gtk::Window& TopLevelWindowGet()
{
    static Gtk::Window window;
    return window;
}

Gtk::Button& TopLevelButtonGet()
{
    static Gtk::Button button("Hello World");
    return button;
}
```

*do not* create the widgets. This will only happen if the functions are called. This is why these lines are added *after* the application has been created:

```cpp
Gtk::Window& win = TopLevelWindowGet();
Gtk::Button& m_button = TopLevelButtonGet();
```

#### Conclusion

If I had to pick a solution, I would choose none of them. In fact, I would avoid "top level" variables (or globals as they are usually called) altogether. They can create nasty bugs, especially if you write concurrent code.
With a gun to my head, however, I have a preference for the `std::unique_ptr` solution. Why? Because the `std::unique_ptr` container is designed to hold resources such as widgets in a way that heap is not a problem. Memory is handled by the smart pointer, not by you. It also gives you more control over the lifespan of the widgets. By calling `std::unique_ptr::reset()`, for example, you can destroy you widgets (if they are no longer needed, for example).